# Does addition on Date column leads to over fitting?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

I'm working on a dataset and what to predict whether it will rain or not, so should I include the date column. I haven't built the model yet, but I think it will lead to overfitting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think datetime is a **vital feature**. Though useful feature could be the season but now-a-days it's changing rapidly due to climate change and so on.

Anyways as it's a **time-series** problem the results are much more dependent on the condition of prior days but of course there are subtle changes which makes it harder to predict.

There are some existing works you can find below:

- https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2761/8afb77c5081d942640333528943149a66edd.pdf
  (used 2 prior days info as features)
- https://stackabuse.com/using-machine-learning-to-predict-the-weather-part-1/ (3 prior days info as features)

I think these are some good starting point.